# JPA Query: JOIN Issue

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am having a JPA Query:

```
<named-query name="AUDIT_QUERY">
    <query>
select rx.rxNumber, rx.rxFillStatus.id, tx.rx.rxaaId, tx.id, tx.drugUpc.id, 
tx.compound.id, tx.tpSpecialServiceFee.id,tx.txHistoryDrugUpc.id, 
tx.txHistoryCompound.id, tx.txHistoryTpSpecialServiceFee.id, 
tx.txHistoryRx.id, tx.txNumber,tx.txStatus.id,tx.txAdjudicationStatus.id, 
tx.serviceDate, tx.createDatetime, tx.txQuantity, tx.remainingQuantity, tx.daysSupply, 
tx.ppTotal, tx.tpPaidTotal, tx.adjustedTotal, sig.sigDescriptionStoreLanguage , 
sig.sigDescriptionPatientLanguage , tx.serviceDate
from 
Rx rx JOIN FETCH Tx tx JOIN TxSig sig WHERE rx.rxaaId = tx.rx.rxaaId
and tx.txSig.id = sig.id WHERE 
rx.patient.id = ? 
order by tx.serviceDate desc, tx.txNumber desc,
tx.id desc
    </query>
</named-query>
```

While parsing, hibernate throws error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: WHERE near line 1, column 620 [select rx.rxNumber, rx.rxFillStatus.id, tx.rx.rxaaId, tx.id, tx.drugUpc.id, tx.compound.id, tx.tpSpecialServiceFee.id,tx.txHistoryDrugUpc.id, tx.txHistoryCompound.id, tx.txHistoryTpSpecialServiceFee.id, tx.txHistoryRx.id, tx.txNumber,tx.txStatus.id,tx.txAdjudicationStatus.id, tx.serviceDate, tx.createDatetime, tx.txQuantity, tx.remainingQuantity, tx.daysSupply, tx.ppTotal, tx.tpPaidTotal, tx.adjustedTotal, sig.sigDescriptionStoreLanguage , sig.sigDescriptionPatientLanguage , tx.serviceDate from com.sdm.hw.rx.dao.entity.Rx rx JOIN FETCH Tx tx JOIN TxSig sig WHERE rx.rxaaId = tx.rx.rxaaId and tx.txSig.id = sig.id WHERE rx.patient.id = ? order by tx.serviceDate desc, tx.txNumber desc, tx.id desc]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Giriraj

Answer (score 0):

To define the conditions for a join the keyword `ON` is used instead of `WHERE`. If I see it right you got that wrong.

```
SELECT
    rx.rxNumber,
    rx.rxFillStatus.id,
    tx.rx.rxaaId,
    tx.id,
    tx.drugUpc.id,
    tx.compound.id,
    tx.tpSpecialServiceFee.id,
    tx.txHistoryDrugUpc.id,
    tx.txHistoryCompound.id,
    tx.txHistoryTpSpecialServiceFee.id,
    tx.txHistoryRx.id,
    tx.txNumber,
    tx.txStatus.id,
    tx.txAdjudicationStatus.id,
    tx.serviceDate,
    tx.createDatetime,
    tx.txQuantity,
    tx.remainingQuantity,
    tx.daysSupply,
    tx.ppTotal,
    tx.tpPaidTotal,
    tx.adjustedTotal,
    sig.sigDescriptionStoreLanguage,
    sig.sigDescriptionPatientLanguage,
    tx.serviceDate
FROM
    Rx rx
JOIN
FETCH
    Tx tx
JOIN
    TxSig sig
ON
    rx.rxaaId = tx.rx.rxaaId
AND tx.txSig.id = sig.id
WHERE
    rx.patient.id = ?
ORDER BY
    tx.serviceDate DESC,
    tx.txNumber DESC,
    tx.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply stone. But JPA 2.0 uses WHERE in place of ON. ON is proposed in JPA 2.1 draft.

Comment: @user1752663 Do you have a source for this? I find it hard to believe that. If it was so a natural join with selection would be impossible. You would only have one `WHERE` and couldn't tell if it's the join criteria or the selection.